# Selenium or Chromedriver randomly stopped working with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a few scripts in Python that use selenium and chromedriver for web scraping. They have worked fine for months but as of last night (04/06/2017) they started giving errors when I try to do anything with chromedriver. For example, these two lines of code produce a not secure error inside the browser address bar.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_window_position(-10000, 0)
```

My scripts were made using Python 3.5. I installed Python 3.6 but I am still using idle from 3.5. I installed Python 3.6 about 2 weeks ago and didn't have any problems with my scripts working. Why did this randomly start happening, which one of the two is the problem, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading the newest version of chromedriver.exe and replacing the old chromedriver my issue was resolved. I still get a not secure error on the browser when it opens but my scripts continue to run now.